# error TS2345: Argument of type 'X' is not assignable to parameter of type 'X[]'

Tags: angular, typescript

Currently, there is a strange behaviour when trying to create a new object in Typescript. There are two classes:

```
export class SkaterDrawn {

    private ID;
    private name;
    ...

constructor(input?:any) {
    this.ID = input.ID;
    ...
}


export class SkaterDrawnTeam extends SkaterDrawn {
    private skaters:SkaterDrawn[];

    constructor(skaters:SkaterDrawn[]) {
        super(skaters[0]);
        this.skaters = skaters;
    }
    ...
}
```

`this.registeredSkaters` contains an array of elements of type `SkaterDrawn`. Now I'm grouping this array into an array of chunks, like this:

```
this.registeredSkaters = this.registeredSkaters.groupBy('teamID');
this.registeredSkaters = Object.values(this.registeredSkaters);
```

This outputs:

```
[
    [SkaterDrawn,SkaterDrawn,SkaterDrawn],
    [SkaterDrawn,SkaterDrawn,SkaterDrawn],
    [SkaterDrawn,SkaterDrawn,SkaterDrawn]
]
```

Now I'm trying to create a new Object out of this:

```
let teams = this.registeredSkaters.map((item:SkaterDrawn[]) => 
    new SkaterDrawnTeam(item);
})
```

I expected to get an array of `SkaterDrawnTeam`, but the compilation fails with

```
ERROR in src/app/competition/components/drawing/drawing.component.ts(166,30): 
error TS2345: Argument of type 'SkaterDrawn' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SkaterDrawn[]'.
Type 'SkaterDrawn' is missing the following properties from type 'SkaterDrawn[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 35 more.
```

`Line 166,30` is the line where I try to do `new SkaterDrawnTeam(item)` I don't know why this fails. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Thx so much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the SkaterDrawn[] is not same as (typeof SkaterDrawn)[]

```
let teams = this.registeredSkaters.map((item: (typeof SkaterDrawn)[]) => { 
               return new SkaterDrawnTeam(item);
             });
```

And then change your class as

```
export class SkaterDrawnTeam extends SkaterDrawn {
    private skaters:(typeof SkaterDrawn)[];

    constructor(skaters:(typeof SkaterDrawn)[]) {
        super(skaters);
        this.skaters = skaters;
    }
}
```

[https://stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r7jjme)

Comment: I tried this too, but it results with the same error

Comment: BTW: When I output the `item` in den map to the console I get an array of `SkaterDrawn `

Comment: Since you are getting an array, you can use inner map. Updating my answer

Comment: I guess there is a small misunderstanding because `SkaterDrawnTeam`expects to the array of `SkaterDrawn`. When I do:

`     let teams = this.registeredSkaters.map((item:SkaterDrawn[]) => 
         new SkaterDrawnTeam(item);
    })
`
it works. But why not with my typing...

Comment: Thx for your Stackblitz. I saw that it is working in the demo. But for what reason ever I can't get it to work in my project (`error TS2345: Argument of type '(item: (typeof SkaterDrawn)[]) => SkaterDrawnTeam' is not assignable to parameter of type`). So I changed it now to `new SkaterDrawnTeam(<any>item)` - that works. No idea what's wrong on my side.